# How to add a field on Date Formats setting form?

Tags: forms, settings, date-preferences

I want to add a field under `Localization > Date Formats`. What is the correct procedure to do this?

This is what I tried. I added an entry in `Localization.settings.php`, `CRM/Admin/Form/Setting.php`'s *$_settings* array property and `CRM/Core/Config/MagicMerge.php` and, added a corresponding record on `civicrm_settings` table and cleared the cache. The field is not showing up. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you managed to solve this issue Dilip? Was it to do with caching after all?

Comment: @John No. :/ I haven't solved this issue yet. I am stuck at another issue. http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11972/regen-sh-call-to-undefined-function-db-query

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this by editing core files. I would implement the buildForm and postProcess hooks in a module extension.

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Hook+Reference

But having said that I probably also wouldn't add it to a core form, I would make a settings page for my extension, which is just a module extension that implements the "add a basic web form" instructions at the first link.