# regen.sh - Call to undefined function db_query()

Tags: database, settings

So I was following this [doc](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Settings+Reference#SettingsReference-AddingANewSettingtoCiviCRMCore) to add a new setting which asked me to run `bin/regen.sh` script. But running the script failed with the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function db_query() in /opt/buildkit/build/mytestbuild/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/DrupalBase.php on line 303
```

Now I cannot access CiviCRM at all. I get the following message. Drupal works fine though.

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error message
CRM_Core_Exception: Found installation canary. This suggests that something went wrong with tracking installation process. Please post to forum or JIRA. in Civi\Core\InstallationCanary::check() (line 53 of /opt/buildkit/build/mytestbuild/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/InstallationCanary.php).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two concerns here - how to get `mytestbuild` working again - and how to get `regen.sh` to work.

## Get `mytestbuild` working

The quickfix is to drop the table `civicrm_install_canary`.

The more general fix is to put your codebase to a pristine state (e.g. no local changes/patches; check out the official upstream branch; [`git scan status`](https://civicrm.org/blogs/totten/developer-tip-managing-multiple-git-repositories) may help). Then you can create a pristine DB using one of these commands:

- `civibuild restore mytestbuild` - This is faster -- it loads a SQL snapshot from the last time you ran `civibuild`.
- `civibuild reinstall mytestbuild` - This is slower -- it drops the Drupal+Civi databases, deletes any config files, and recreates them.

## Get `regen.sh` working

This appears to be a regression affecting `regen.sh`. To determine this, I did a few things:

1. Checkout the latest code from `master` and run regen.sh. See the same problem.
2. Clear out uncommitted changes (e.g. `git checkout -- sql/civicrm_generated.mysql`)
3. Repeat above, but checkout tag `4.7.0` instead of branch `master`. (When jumping among different versions, I usually use `./bin/givi checkout <TAG>` because that checks out corresponding tags in `packages/`, `drupal/`, etc. The need to )

After spot-checking a few tags, I determined the problem arose somewhere after 4.7.0 and before 4.7.2. Since the context involves `bin/` and the error involves `CRM/Utils/System`, we can make an educated guess that there was a change in one of those folders and skim the log:

```
git log 4.7.0..4.7.2 bin/
git log 4.7.0..4.7.2 CRM/Utils/System
git log -p 4.7.0..4.7.2 bin/
git log -p 4.7.0..4.7.2 CRM/Utils/System
```

I'm pretty sure that the regression occurred due to https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/40d5632a25086d7c963538f2b6daf2a2546e16a6 ; undoing that patch allows `regen.sh` to run,  but you'd need to read/think a bit more figure out a proper fix.

Comment: Follow up: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8435

Comment: Checked out `4.7.0` tag and it worked. Thanks :)